# How to put this Javascript function return in a HiddenField c# object?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, hiddenfield

I need to put the return of the function `validarCartao()` into that HiddenField value. The `alert(response.brand.name)` works fine but I cant get this, even if I move the HiddenField to inside the function. I've tried lots of ways but nothing works. I really appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks.

```js
var hiddenBandeiraTemp = document.getElementById('<%=hiddenBandeira.ClientID%>');

hiddenBandeiraTemp.value = validarCartao(tbNumeroCartao.value);

function validarCartao(element) {

            var cardNum = element.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
            var card_invalid = 'Número do cartão inválido.';

            if (cardNum.length >= 6) {
                PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand({
                    cardBin: cardNum.substr(0, 6),
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (typeof response.brand.name != 'undefined') {
                            alert(response.brand.name); // OK
                            return response.brand.name; // <<--
                        } else {
                            alert(card_invalid);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(card_invalid);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: you can't return from an asychronous function unless you are returning a promise. Consume the response inside the success handler

Comment: Please @charlietfl could you show me how? 'hiddenBandeiraTemp.value = response.brand.name;' doesnt work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` statement that you put inside the `success` callback will return a value for the function `success()` not for the function `validarCartao()`

```
success: function (response) {
    if (typeof response.brand.name != 'undefined') {
        alert(response.brand.name); // OK
        return response.brand.name; // <<--
    } else {
        alert(card_invalid);
    }
}
```

Moreover, as the function `PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand()` seems to be asynchronous, it is impossible to return its value inside `validarCartao()`. In my opinion, this would be a better solution:

```
var hiddenCompradorIdTemp = document.getElementById('<%=hiddenCompradorId.ClientID%>');

validarCartao(tbNumeroCartao.value);

function validarCartao(element) {

            var cardNum = element.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
            var card_invalid = 'Número do cartão inválido.';

            if (cardNum.length >= 6) {
                PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand({
                    cardBin: cardNum.substr(0, 6),
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (typeof response.brand.name != 'undefined') {
                            alert(response.brand.name); // OK
                            hiddenBandeiraTemp.value = response.brand.name;
                        } else {
                            alert(card_invalid);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(card_invalid);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you but 'hiddenBandeiraTemp.value = response.brand.name;' is not working. 
'alert(response.brand.name)' works but when I put in a var or in the hiddenBandeiraTemp.value nothing happen. Do you have another suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Are `hiddenCompradorIdTemp` and `hiddenBandeiraTemp` two different elements ? Is there any error in the web console ?

Comment: I forgot to show you one line below
`var hiddenCompradorIdTemp = ...`
its
`var hiddenBandeiraTemp = document.getElementById('<%=hiddenBandeira.ClientID%>');`

Comment: Ok, that could be the reason because I don't see nothing wrong with my answer. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/4tj0atqg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
Now its working fine. I wasnt putting the `hiddenBandeiraTemp` declaration inside the `validarCartao(element)`. Merry xmas!!

```js
function validarCartao(element) {

            var hiddenBandeiraTemp = document.getElementById('<%=hiddenBandeira.ClientID%>');

            var cardNum = element.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
            var card_invalid = 'Número do cartão inválido.';

            if (cardNum.length >= 6) {
                PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand({
                    cardBin: cardNum.substr(0, 6),
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (typeof response.brand.name != 'undefined') {
                            hiddenBandeiraTemp.value = response.brand.name.toString();
                        } else {
                            alert(card_invalid);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(card_invalid);
                    },
                    complete: function (response) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: why did you post this answer after @nquocnghia went to the trouble of helping you

Comment: sorry, just to complement. the wrong was the line `var hiddenBandeiraTemp = ...` outside the function validarCartao()